# How can I use ProjectLocker instead of Git in laravel?

Tags: laravel, repository, projectlocker

Is there any setting available in Laravel to use [ProjectLocker](http://projectlocker.com/) or other repository ?

Comment: what setting do you mean?

Comment: Any ways to use other repository than git.

Comment: You can download Laravel as an archive and commit it to any VCS you like.